# CakePHP 3.x How to call Api -> controller -> action From Src -> controller -> action?

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.1

We're trying to build another app for API purposes so according our requirements we've made changes in the composer file to autoload api Controller and Model etc.

Like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src"
        ,"App\\Controller\\": "./api/Controller"
        ,"App\\Model\\": "./api/Model"
    }
},
```

So now our cakephp 3.x folder structure is as below:

```
project root
    - api -> inside of this folder we've same structure as in the src folder to use for API.
    - src
    - config
    - logs
    - plugins
    - vendor
    - etc etc...
```

we're trying to call controller / action which is located in the API folder as below:

```
api -> Controller -> UserControler.php -> login action
```

trying to Calling from:

```
src / controller / action
```

Is there any way how to call ?

We can use `requestAction` but we've same controller and action name exist in both folders SRC and API like UsersControler -> login Action in that case might be SRC controller and action will be called and this is the main problem which how to resolve ?

Anyone have idea please share your thoughts and knowledge.

Thanks!

Comment: The need to invoke a controller from within a controller indicates that your application design is flawed. I don't really get this anyways, why do you need to separate stuff like that? Why don't you use plugins or maybe even prefix routing?

Comment: that make sense we can build plugin for that.

Comment: @ndm can you please let me know how we get post and get request data from controller to plugin controller / action ?

Comment: You shouldn't do that at all! As mentioned initially, the need to indicates flawed application design. If this isn't something that can be solved cleanly by extending the target controller, or using the plugins models, then you most probably need to rethink your appplication structure. You might get better answers if you come up with a comprehensible real world example that shows what exactly you are trying to do.